# What the website name bloging service by wordpress mu?

Tags: service

What the website name service blogging by Wordpress mu ?

Please give me 10-20 website thanks.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question. Someone downvoted it, but it seems like you might be having a problem translating to English.

Comment: Looking at your question, it looks like your asking us to give you a list of websites that use WordPress multisite. If that's what you're asking, then your question isn't a good fit for this site. If it isn't, could you clarify what you mean (leave a comment here beginning with `@christofian`) and I'll see if I can reopen it. Also, if you're having problems translating, tell me and I'll try to edit your questions to make them clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Rephrase the question?

http://wordpress.com
http://space.live.com
http://www.blogsome.com
http://www.blogsome.com
http://okayblog.net